# Как сделать изображения одинаковыми по размеру

Tags: html, bootstrap

Использую bootstrap 4, не получается сделать все картинки одного размера.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код

```
<main role="main" class="container containerWidth">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 wrap_images">
        <img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/img/1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 wrap_images">
        <img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/img/2.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 wrap_images">
        <img class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" src="/img/3.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: у класса wrap_images задайте точные размеры

Comment: тогда он изменит размеры контейнера из фреймворка. тот еще костыль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установите ширину изображений равную ширине родительского контейнера:

```
.img-fluid {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Или задайте фиксированный размер:

```
.img-fluid {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Если не выйдет, скиньте ссылку на сайт.

Так же, более надежный вариант, задать жестко высоту и ширину изображений, но тогда они могут деформироваться(растянуться):

```
.img-fluid {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Не получается, при первом варианте никаких изменений, по второму все картинки стали меньше, но у центральной картинке все равно высота больше. Скинуть ссылку не могу потому что сайт локально работает(

Comment: Тогда третий вариант

Comment: Вот с 3 чётенько, спасибо)